# Embedded Interop REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG error on client machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, interop, com-interop

I've compiled my app as x86.
I'm using a VB6 COM Interop in my app.
I've set the reference to "Embed Interop type=Yes", "Isolated=No".

I don't need to install anything on the client machine, not even the "Interop.MyDLL.dll", it magically worked without installing anything.

I can test this easily on my test computer, it works just fine.

Now, on a client machine the error "System.TypeInitializationException, class not registered, HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)" is thrown when I try to access the DLL.

It occured after I recompiled the app and deployed it. Before that, it worked fine.

What might be the culprit here?

Comment: You don't have to register the interop dll (it's not a COM component, just metadata definitions). But you must register the VB6 COM component (dll, ocx, etc.). There's no magic.

Comment: @SimonMourier OMG, you're right. The thing was that I installed it to SysWow64 on my test machine some ages ago, so I didn't notice that I needed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you could make your comment the reply. Then other dummies like me can find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not "magic" with COM, you must register the VB6 COM component (dll, ocx, etc.).

The interop .NET dll is not a COM component, it just contains metadata/binding from .NET to COM, so it doesn't need to be registered.

PS: in fact, you don't *have* to register, you just need to give clients a way to find you, so there's also the possibility to use [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx), but it can be more work than simply register a bunch of dlls.